# Can't save custom field data: form submit function doesn't fire

Tags: forms

I've added custom "markup" field to the commerce_product table, next I've implemented hook_form_FORM-ID_alter, but submit function doesn't executed.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please remove the code that is not necessary to answer the question. Knowing you implement other hooks is not necessary to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, but why don't You answer?

Comment: Can you call `debug($form)` or `dpm($form)` (if devel is installed) in your `hook_form_alter()` and check the submit function that is specified?

Comment: Custom submit function in it's place, but not invoked. (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42690200/form-submit.PNG)

Answer (score 1):

If you add the custom field through hook_form_alter. You need to store the data manually in your custom table by using your custom submit handler..    Otherwise you could use the below code in your *.install file

```
function MYMODULE_enable() {
  // Check if our field is not already created.
  if (!field_info_field('field_myField')) {

    // Create the field base.
    $field = array(
      'field_name' => 'field_myField', 
      'type' => 'text', 
    );
    field_create_field($field);

    // Create the field instance on the bundle.
    $instance = array(
      'field_name' => 'field_myField', 
      'entity_type' => 'user', 
      'label' => 'My Field Name', 
      'bundle' => 'user', 
      // If you don't set the "required" property then the field wont be required by default.
      'required' => TRUE,
      'settings' => array(
        // Here you inform either or not you want this field showing up on the registration form.
        'user_register_form' => 1,
      ),
      'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'textfield',
      ), 
    );
    field_create_instance($instance);
  }
}
```